# C# Character count condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

how can i put condition here. Like if i Inputted a 4 digit character, it'll put a Prefix which is "F-".

```
try
{
    Service1 ws = new Service1();
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13 && button1.Enabled == true)
    {
        inputtxt = F.Text.ToString();
        showpic(inputtxt);
        if (ws.VerifyEID(inputtxt) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an incorrect Employee ID. Please try again!", "Attendance Monitoring System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            F.Text = null;
        }



        else
        {
             panel1.Visible = false;
             SqlToText(inputtxt);
             ShowOffset(inputtxt);
             if (BtnTimeIn.Visible == true)
             {
                 BtnTimeIn.Focus();
             }
             else
             {
                 BtnTimeOut.Focus();
             }
         }

     }
```

Help me please, thankyou.

Comment: You code does not seem to be complete and will not compile in it's current state.

Comment: Ok, so you want to prefix a string with "f", and I'm assuming you want it where you have the incomplete line `if (inputtext =` ?

Comment: My bad, Disregard that. I was editing the code while im posting here, so i accidentally included it. Uh, sir can u help me

Comment: And sir, i want a prefix of "F-" if they input a 4-digit character..

Like, fore example. I entered 0049.

then it will be automatically be F-0049.

but if they already inputted "F-0049" then nothing should be change.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this in your code:

```
inputtxt = inputtxt.StartsWith("F-") ? inputtxt : "F-" + inputtxt;
```

But I would personally have that prefix on the textbox to make it clear for the users what to type in and have them type less characters.